# `multiple definition of` lots of variables error - is my make file incorrect?

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

I am getting an error when I compile `multiple definition of` lots of variables. For example:

```
/tmp/ccwHwJ7t.o:(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `serial_number'
/tmp/ccmT1XNI.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
```

All the variables are located in `ftdi.h`, which is included by `main.c`. Is there something wrong with my make file that is causing this to be included twice? or am I looking in the wrong directio.

```
SSHELL = /bin/sh
CC    = gcc

APP = npi_usb_ftdi
INC = include

INCDIRS +=-I${INC}

CFLAGS= ${INCDIRS} -Wall -Wextra
LIBS = libftd2xx.a  -ldl -lpthread -lrt


all: ${APP}

${APP}: src/main.c src/ftdi.c src/vt100.c src/monitor.c
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} src/main.c src/ftdi.c src/vt100.c src/monitor.c -o ${APP} ${LIBS} 

ftdi.o:
    ${CC} -c -o src/ftdi.o src/ftdi.c

vt100.o:
    ${CC} -c -o src/vt100.o src/vt100.c

monitor.o:
    ${CC} -c -o src/monitor.o src/monitor.c


clean:
    rm -f src/*.o ; rm -f src/*~ ; rm -f *~ ; rm -f ${APP}
```

Comment: First of all, never put variable/function definitions in header files. Second, always use header guards (`#ifndef FOO_H`...) when writing a header file.

Comment: Is `ftdi.h` also included in `ftdi.c` or any other file?

Comment: seems `serial_number` is already defined in the library you are pointing . just to check try after renaming the variable

Comment: @Lundin thanks, silly mistake having variable definitions in header. Apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably include the .h file in other source files too. No problem, but only in one source file should the variables be declared and in the others just defined. I use:

```
// ftdi.h
#ifndef EXTERN
# define EXTERN extern
#endif
EXTERN int examplevar;

// main.c
#define EXTERN
#include "ftdi.h"

// ftdi.c
#include "ftdi.h"
```